# Работа с одного компьютера на разных аккаунтах github/gitlab

Tags: ubuntu, github, gitlab

Есть аккаунт на гитлаб и аккаунт (другая почта и имя) на гитхаб. Один проект лежит на одном ресурсе, другой на другой. Как настроить работу с обоими проектами с одной машины и одного пользователя?

Моя попытка:
Был и остался полностью настроенный гитлаб. В аккаунт гитхаб я добавил новый rsa(сгенерированный дополнительно с именем rsa2) ключ с моей машины. Но ни один репозиторий из хитхаба даже не клонируется

```
Клонирование в «test»…
ERROR: Repository not found.
fatal: Не удалось прочитать из внешнего репозитория.

Удостоверьтесь, что у вас есть необходимые права доступа
и репозиторий существует.
```

Comment: В папке репозитория выполняете команды `git config user.name имя_пользователя` и `git config user.email почта`. При коммитах имя пользователя и почта будут браться из локальных настроек репозитория.

Comment: @insolor а как скачать по ssh сам репозиторий без этого конфига

Comment: Это никак не влияет на ssh. Для github и gitlab просто отдельные ключи настраиваете, и клонируете.

Comment: @insolor как мой компьютер помёт каким именн ключом обращаться к  github а каким к gitlab

Comment: Вот честно, не интересовался данным вопросом. Но у меня подключение разными ключами к github и к рабочему gitlab без проблем работает.

Comment: @insolor  у меня не работает как раз и я поэтому интересуюсь. Гитлаб полность настроен, а с гитхаба ни один проект скопировать не даёт, хотя ключ добавил(отдельно сгенерил новый rsa2 и добавил).

Comment: Добавьте все это в вопрос. В том числе ошибки, которые github пишет при клонировании

Comment: Репозиторий публичный или приватный? как remote url выглядит?

Comment: @insolor приватный     git@github.com:githubName/test.git

Comment: `git remote -v` url'ы c `https://` или с `ssh://` показывает?

Comment: я же склонировать не могу  - пишет > git remote -v
fatal: не найден git репозиторий (или один из родительских каталогов): .git

Comment: Ок, тогда смотрите по справке, пожалуй начиная с "Check your SSH access" (будем считать, что адрес правильно скопировали): https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/creating-and-managing-repositories/troubleshooting-cloning-errors#error-repository-not-found